# I'm trying to expose a folder size in Node exporter but messes up. any suggestions?

Tags: linux, ceph, prometheus

This wasn't the case for a few months but suddenly my Node exporter in the server service messed up.

```
Oct 02 10:13:01 nodefs01 node_exporter[117252]: time="2023-10-02T10:13:01Z" level=error msg="error gathering metrics: [from Gatherer #2] collected metric \"node_filesystem_device_error\" { label:<name:\"device\" value:\"ceph-fuse\" > label:<name:\"fstype\" value:\"fuse.ceph-fuse\" > label:<name:\"mountpoint\" value:\"/var/lib/ceph/ceph-alerting/cephfs\" > gauge:<value:1 > } was collected before with the same name and label values\n" source="log.go:172"
```

Here's my mount if it helps

```
    [root@nodefs01 textfile_collector]# cat /proc/mounts | grep ceph
    tmpfs /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-36 tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
    tmpfs /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-46 tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
    tmpfs /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-31 tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
    tmpfs /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-15 tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
    tmpfs /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-75 tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
    tmpfs /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-73 tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
    tmpfs /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-74 tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
    tmpfs /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-7 tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
    tmpfs /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-28 tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
    tmpfs /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-13 tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
    tmpfs /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-43 tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
    tmpfs /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-38 tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
    tmpfs /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-20 tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
    tmpfs /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-72 tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
    tmpfs /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-23 tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
    tmpfs /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-3 tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
    ceph-fuse /var/lib/ceph/ceph-alerting/cephfs fuse.ceph-fuse ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other 0 0
    ceph-fuse /var/lib/ceph/ceph-alerting/cephfs fuse.ceph-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other 0 0
    ceph-fuse /var/lib/ceph/ceph-alerting/cephfs fuse.ceph-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other 0 0
```

I've tried looking for similar issues but it seems like this is the first. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've checked my mounts

I'm expecting the metrics to be exposed on the Prometheus Node exporter.

This wasn't the case for a few months but suddenly my Node exporter in the server service messed up.

```
Oct 02 10:13:01 nodefs01 node_exporter[117252]: time="2023-10-02T10:13:01Z" level=error msg="error gathering metrics: [from Gatherer #2] collected metric \"node_filesystem_device_error\" { label:<name:\"device\" value:\"ceph-fuse\" > label:<name:\"fstype\" value:\"fuse.ceph-fuse\" > label:<name:\"mountpoint\" value:\"/var/lib/ceph/ceph-alerting/cephfs\" > gauge:<value:1 > } was collected before with the same name and label values\n" source="log.go:172"
```

-duplicate removed by edit-

I've tried looking for similar issues but it seems like this is the first. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've checked my mounts

I'm expecting the metrics to be exposed on the Prometheus Node exporter.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to have the same ceph-fuse mount three times (one of them read-only)?